# Python: How to warn user of duplicate value in list

Tags: python, list, duplicates, append, warnings

I'm trying to write a program that allows a user to enter as many integers as they decide. As you can see, they will decide this with 'lengthList =....'. My aim is to not only remove duplicate entries, but to also notify the user of the duplicate. I've managed to remove duplicates, but can't work out how to notify the user that their entry has been removed. e.g "28 has already been entered. Removed from list."

thanks

```
result = "0"
intList = [] 
LengthList = int(input("Please enter the amount of numbers")        
while len(result) < LengthList:
 userNumber = input("Please input a number: ")
 intList.append(userNumber)
 removeDuplicate = set(intList)
 result = list(removeDuplicate)
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
# Creating the results list
results = list()

# Casting the string input to int()
amount_of_numbers = int(input("Please enter the amount of numbers: "))

# While lenght of results is lower than the provided amount of numbers
while len(results) < amount_of_numbers:

    ## Casting the string input to int() since we want to store it as an integer and not as a string
    userNumber = int(input("Please input a number: "))

    ## If the input number is not already in results list
    if userNumber not in results:
        # Appending the input number to results list
        results.append(userNumber)
    else:
        # Printing a message saying that the number already exists in results list
        print ("{} has already been entered".format(userNumber))
# Printing results list
print (results)
```

**Output:**

```
➜  python numbers.py
Please enter the amount of numbers: 4
Please input a number: 1
Please input a number: 2
Please input a number: 3
Please input a number: 1
1 has already been entered
Please input a number: 2
2 has already been entered
Please input a number: 3
3 has already been entered
Please input a number: 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this manually, as in not using 'not in'?

Comment: There are a lot of ways. This is one: http://dpaste.com/2JB3HS8, and this is another http://dpaste.com/2RDWZR2

Comment: Apparently I need more rep, as soon as I get enough. I will +10 you if possible!

Comment: @JSeal I take your word! Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Try use a list to store the values and test if the inputted value is in it before add the number.
There is my solution to this problem below:

```py
l = []
while True:
    userNumber = input("Please input a number: ")
    if userNumber not in l:
        userNumber = l.append(userNumber)
        print(l)
    else:
        print(f'{userNumber} already exist in the list, and your list is {l}')
```

Output:

```
Please input a number: 1
['1']
Please input a number: 1
1 already exist in the list, and your list is ['1']
Please input a number: 2
['1', '2']
Please input a number: 2
2 already exist in the list, and your list is ['1', '2']
Please input a number: 3
```